# Connection of Toch Kedei Dibbur to Walking 4 Amot

Tags: talmud-gemara, shiurim-measurements, time

According to [this](http://ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v21/mj_v21i01.html#CB), the gemara compares Toch Kedei Dibbur (the length of time neccasary to greet someone; see [Shalom alecha rebbi (u'mori)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/955/shalom-alecha-rebbi-umori) ) to the time it takes to walk 4 amot (cubits). Thus, with a little math, one can conclude that Toch Kedei Dibbur is 2.16 seconds.

Does anyone know what connection he is referring to? Where does the gemara equate these two units of time?

Comment: Actually, it may be that the poster there is incorrect and there is no such equation. I see where She'arim Metzuyanim Bahalachah (to Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 19:10) [states](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3376&pgnum=125) that תוך כדי דיבור is less than כדי הילוך ד' אמות.

Comment: @msh210 "most people will walk 4 amos at a faster rate than they will 2000". Isn't the gemara referring to the average speed a person walks? In that case, 4 & 2000 will be the same.

Comment: The linked post doesn't mention the greeting aspect of _toch k'dei dibur_, just the basic uninterrupted train of thought idea. Couldn't the inference for that come from Rav Ashi's opinion in [_M'gila_ 27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.27b.17?lang=he), cited by @Alex's citation, that _k'dei hiluch arba amos_ is the threshhold for a continuous train of thought with respect to _t'fila_?

Comment: AFAICT the Gemara never says this, based on a Sefaria search for תוך כדי דיבור and searching those results for אמות - there are no results that contain both phrases, only one or the other.

Comment: followup question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/107243/170