# Shalom Alecha: Rebbi vs. Rebbi u'Mori

Tags: halacha, blessing, shiurim-measurements

A Toch K'dei Dibbur is the amount of time (~3s) that one has to fix a bracha, renege on a deal, etc. The phrase used for this time frame is a machlokes between the Mishnah Berurah (206:12) and the Taz (206:3) whether "U'Mori" is included.

What exactly is the nekudas hamachlokes between these opinions? Why does the Chafetz Chaim leave it out while the Taz includes it?

Related: [Shalom Alecha Rebbi (u'Mori)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/955/shalom-alecha-rebbi-umori) and [How far can I back up in a bracha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/49266/how-far-can-i-back-up-in-a-bracha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Bava Kama 73a. the Gemara says "shalom Alecha Rebbi u'Mori", but the Rashash takes it out based on a Rosh. Also, the manuscripts do not have the word "u'Mori".